# Not sure if this is grammatically correct: Target in-demand candidates for your apprenticeship

Tags: meaning, grammar, expressions, meaning-in-context, business-language

I am a little confused about this slogan that I wrote:

> Target in-demand candidates for your apprenticeship.

I feel this sentence is not complete and could be rephrased to be shorter and clearer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Whether or not it's syntactically correct, I'm not sure it means anything.  (I'm thinking you should try to make it LONGER, so that you can more clearly express what you mean.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's clear what you are trying to say but it did take me twice to read it before I understood. To get rid of that hyphenated word, which I think may be causing the slight confusion, you could say instead:

> Target desired candidates for your apprenticeship.

Comment: I'm not sure 'demanded' is grammatical: I am sure it is extremely peculiar.

Comment: I agree that 'demanded' does sound a bit peculiar, but it is correct.

Comment: I'd use desirable rather than desired.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - But "desired" and "desirable" mean significantly different things.  (And it's still not clear what Opie meant.)

Comment: Thank you for your input please have a look at the site maybe that could help clarify the situation. http://recruitly.co/

Comment: @HotLicks - Agreed, which is why I included both possibilities.

Comment: so the final answer would be 

    Target desirable candidates for your apprenticeship?